# I need merge 2 lines in only one based on other column attribute name

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

I am stuck for some time in this. Imagine that I have this table:

```
diagId | astigmatic
1      | No
1      | Yes
2      | No
3      | No
4      | No
5      | No
5      | Yes
6      | No
```

And I want the output:

```
diagId | astigmatic
1      | Yes
2      | No
3      | No
4      | No
5      | Yes
6      | No
```

So if there is a diagId with Yes and No, I want the Yes tuple to pervail and the No tuple to disappear.

How can I achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is aggregation:

```
select diagid, max(astigmatic) as astigmatic
from t
group by diagid;
```

This works because `'yes'` > `'no'`.

Or, a conceptually similar method but one that is probably faster in Postgres:

```
select distinct on (diagid) t.*
from t
order by diagid, astigmatic desc;
```

Another approach is `or` and `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.astigmatic = 'yes' or
      (t.astigmatic = 'no' and
       not exists (select 1
                   from t t2
                   where t2.id = t.id and
                         t2.astigmatic = 'yes'
                  )
      );
```

The first two method return one row per `id` -- guaranteed.  This last method could return multiple rows, if there are multiple `'yes'`s or `'no'`s for a given `id`.